# A tough rearranging

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In a physics textbook I try to follow some math derivation, and got stuck here:

> First we rearrange Eq. (30.13) to the form
>   $$\frac{di}{i-(\mathcal{E}/R)}=-\frac{R}{L}dt$$

And equation (30.13) is this:

> $$\frac{di}{dt}=\frac{\mathcal{E}-iR}{L}=\frac{\mathcal{E}}{L}-\frac{R}{L}i \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:(30.13)$$

Might be a very simple question... But I would appreciate a hand with this algebraic rearranging on how to come from Eq. (30.13) to that next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{di}{dt} &= \frac{\mathcal{E} - iR}{L} = \frac{\mathcal{E}/R - i}{L/R} \\
\frac{di}{(\mathcal{E}/R - i)dt} &= \frac{1}{L/R} \\
\frac{di}{\mathcal{E}/R - i} &= \frac{1}{L/R} dt \\
\frac{di}{i - \mathcal{E}/R} &= -\frac{R}{L} dt
\end{align}